# How to unittest aiohttp.web applications

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.5, aiohttp

Given an aiohttp.web application with views like this one:

```
async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(body=b"Hello, world")
```

I'm trying to understand how to properly unit-test them.

I normally use Django's own [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example) when writing Django apps, and was looking for something similar for aiohttp.web. I'm not sure this is the right approach or not.

**TL;DR: How do I simulate a request to an `aiohttp.web` app in a unittest?**

Comment: I discovered [webtest-http](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webtest-aiohttp) but I'm not sure this is the "best" or "endorsed" way to do it.

Comment: Not having much luck with webtest-aiohttp, see [ticket on github](https://github.com/sloria/webtest-aiohttp/issues/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create web server and perform real HTTP requests **without simulation**.

See https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/tests/test_client_functional.py for example.